# "including" files in fstab

Tags: filesystems

It would be nice on some systems to break up one big fstab file and replace it with an `fstab` file "including" other files.

Also it would be nice to mount things from a secondary "fstab" file relative to some directory.

So as an example (of the *offset*, or *relative* mount), imagine you have a line in the fstab file:

```
#include foobar.fstab offset=/external_mount
```

in foobar I specify two file systems that are mounted on /foo and /bar. Through the use of the fstab, they are instead mounted on /external_mount/foo and /external_mount/bar.

Is there an equivalent mechanism to do this?

Comment: The other question only answers about 60% of this question. The first is that a single include line for a file works better when often wanting to include or not include filesystems. For example if you remove a hd it is easier to comment out then to move a file. The other is the relative mount which is not addressed by that question at all.